# Will Google Play block license testing email accounts?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have published an app on Google Play and added some Google email addresses to the License Testing Lists for the purpose of testing Google in-app functions.

I have observed that certain Google email accounts can successfully test in-app functions, while others are blocked from testing, resulting in a *"Service connection is disconnected"* debug message, and more there is a strange information *"Google Play In-app Billing API version is less than 3"* is displayed! (I'm sure that Google Play API version is 6.0.1 in the APP).

I am unsure why Google Play would block certain email accounts for testing, and I would like to know where I can find information regarding the reason for this block.

Additionally, I have encountered situations where a Google email account can successfully test in-app functions, only to be blocked by Google in the following days.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code where I process purchases:

```
private fun processPurchases(purchasesResult: Set<Purchase>) {
    val validPurchases = HashSet<Purchase>(purchasesResult.size)
    purchasesResult.forEach { purchase ->
        if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {
            if (purchase.skus.contains(purchaseItem)) {  
                if (isSignatureValid(purchase)) {
                    validPurchases.add(purchase)
                }
            }
        } else if (purchase.purchaseState == Purchase.PurchaseState.PENDING) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Received a pending purchase of SKU: ${purchase.skus}")
            // Handle pending purchases, e.g., confirm with users about the pending
            // purchases, prompt them to complete it, etc.
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderPending)
        } else {
            mContext.toast(R.string.msgOrderError)
        }
    }

    acknowledgeNonConsumablePurchasesAsync(validPurchases.toList())
}
```

Comment: Common reasons for the error you quoted are, (1) there is no account logged into the playstore on that device (2) the device itself does not have any play services installed, (3) the version of the play-services installed on the device is outdated. Especially the latter two may happen when you are testing on an emulator or maybe some custom ROM.